trying to recover 10.17tb of data from a 8tb drive?
Recently, i've been having an issue with an Ubuntu 24.04 Made NTFS drive freezing the whole system, to where the only option is to hard reset the PC. After researching this further, it seems that issue is because Ubuntu doesn't properly format NTFS automatically. Anyways, I opted to just transfer the data over to a new drive utilizing windows, but the drive is unreadable traditionally in windows. I have to use a program called Linux Reader to be able to recover the data on the drive. Mind you, this is an 8tb (7.28tb usable) drive, but the reader program wants to recover 10.17tb of data.
Is there a better way to recover my data utilizing Ubuntu?
Thank you!

Please have a look at this link and edit the question to add some details. BTW your comment about Ubuntu not formatting NTFS is not correct. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask . As for your Windows transfer program that is off topic on this Ubuntu only site. Ask the makers of that program why.

What more information is needed? I mentioned the OS's, File system, issue, and goal.
The ubuntu not formatting NTFS properly seems to be something mentioned in many of the threads i've looked at on this very site. Also, notice how i said automatically. Using the disks program to format, apparently Ubuntu doesn't reserve space it should, and that's what causes the freezing. You can properly format the drives through CLI, but it seemed many recommended formatting on windows before plugging into Ubuntu.
Edited this comment for grammar.

There is no mention of the version of Ubuntu.  As your question still is mostly about the Windows transfer program it is still off topic here.

edited to include 24.04 and interest in using ubuntu to recover the data.

Why would you ever use a foreign OS to repair a Windows partition? Use Windows for that. It has perfect repair toole for a botched journaling.

Seeing as the partition was created on Ubuntu, and is still somewhat usable there, i thought that would be the best way to repair/recover the data. What repair tool are you referencing, and will it work since without 3rd party software, windows doesn't even acknowledge it has partitions, let alone data?

I've tried transferring the main directories via Linux Reader 'individually', and this seems to have consumed significantly less space, however, there's also about 200,000 files, or 3tb worth of data missing. I'm using the properties tab on to figure out what directory is missing files, however, this is taking a significant amount of time as there's over 2.5 million files on the drive i'm transferring the data from, and it only allows 1 folder at a time otherwise the 'search' hangs infinitely. (using ubuntu 24.04 for this)
If anyone has a better solution, please still feel free to suggest.
